# Adding GenericSetup-created folders to the globalnav

Tags: navigation, plone, genericsetup

I'm using GenericSetup to create a single container which I'd like to appear in the globalnav once the package is activated.

Is it possible to do this programmatically?

Comment: I think this is the default in Plone 4.

Comment: If it is, I've accidentally altered something in the site setup so it doesn't work this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a more fine grained control on the creation of contents during product install I'd suggest the use of a `setuphandlers.py` instead of a genericsetup step ([here](http://keeshink.blogspot.com/2009/02/creating-portal-content-in.html) an example)

Comment: Thank you, that helped with a bunch of things.